# Chrome continues running even when Mac should be is asleep

Tags: mac, macos, sleep-wake, battery, google-chrome

I have the latest version of Chrome running on my Mac. I've noticed that even when I close the old intending to put my computer to sleep, Chrome continues running. I know this is the case because I have a Google Voice extension installed. It makes a "ding" noise when I receive a text and that noise comes out of my Mac even when it's supposed to be sleeping.

How do I make Chrome go to sleep along with my Mac? It's sucking the battery dry!

Comment: Well if chrome works then the system isn't sleeping.

Comment: could you change the ding sound to find out if it is something else, and easy to confirm by looking at the time stamp of the message

Comment: With the previous OS X release, Mountain Lion, a feature was added called Power Nap that allows certain processes to run periodically while a Mac is sleeping. I'm not clear on whether third-party apps can do the same; the feature is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion#Other_updates

Comment: @Buscar웃, I'm not sure I know what you mean... I know that it's that Chrome extension. Nothing else makes that same sound. And it happens when I get a text... It's not a question of whether Chrome is running... Because it is...

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, I believe you... But that's not a solution. The Mac is supposed to go to sleep when I close the lid. Regardless, this happens when I explicitly tell my Mac to sleep (not just close the lid).

Comment: In an Apple discussions thread, I see a recommendation to open Terminal and run `pmset -g assertions`. There is a flag called PreventSystemSleep. If it reports 1 on your system instead of 0, this command may also report which app is preventing sleep on your machine.

Comment: @bneely Looks like it's reporting 0... And BackgroundTask is also reporting 0...

Comment: @bneely, I took a video of it making noise when I do a hangout: https://plus.google.com/+KentCDodds/posts/ZNcBBrQwXPd

Comment: does it always happen or just every so often? The Power Nap runs pretty much every background process so probably also hangouts

Comment: I'm pretty sure it happens when I close my lid, but not when I explicitly put it to sleep (clicking"sleep"). But I have disabled power nap for both when it's on battery and when it's on the power adapter...

Answer (score -1):

sure you dont have sleep turned off in power options might be on for battery use but not battery

Comment: Could you expand your answer to clarify what you're talking about?